# KML file with multiple ground overlays

Tags: kml, overlay, multi-geometry

I have geolocated imagery which I would like to plot in Google Earth. I have the 4 corner points of each image, and I am currently laying the images down using GroundOverlay and gx:LatLonQuad.

My problem is that I have a lot of images (they are in sets of 20-25, and I have 10 or 20 of these sets to lay down), and these KMLs will be ingested into another program. I would like to have all the images in each set of 20-25 in a single KML file.

The images in a set are close together (in fact, they are contiguous) and about 200 yards wide. Although the individual images in a set are contiguous and quadrilaterals, the overall shape (of all the contiguous images in a set) does not form a rectangle or quadrilateral, but more of a zigzag path.

Is there a feature that works like MultiGeometry for shapes which I can use with GroundOverlay and gx:LatLonQuad to put multiple ground overlaid images in one KML?

My individual KMLs look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
<GroundOverlay>
  <Icon>
    <href>files\image1.jpg</href>
  </Icon>
  <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
  <gx:LatLonQuad>
    <coordinates>
       ...image 1 coordinates here...
    </coordinates>
  </gx:LatLonQuad>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

I would like to have a single KML file with multiple ground overlays, with all the images in the same "files" folder. Is there a way to do this, or something equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, KML has a Folder tag that you can use for this.  You could also just use a Document tag.  The stripped-down example below shows it with Document, but you could substitute a Folder, or put multiple Folders in a Document.

```
<?xml>
<kml>
  <Document>
    <name>my geolocated images</name>
    <GroundOverlay>
      ...
    </GroundOverlay>
    <GroundOverlay>
      ...
    </GroundOverlay>
    <GroundOverlay>
      ...
    </GroundOverlay>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

See the KML Reference for all the details on the [Document](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#document) and [Folder](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#folder) tags. Let us know if that works, or if you have more questions.

Comment: Worked perfectly just as indicated - thank you so much!